# "Attempt to index local..." Why am I getting this error?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Lua and trying to get things sorted in my head. I tried this code:

```
function newCarousel(images) 
    local slideToImage = function() 
        print("ah!")
    end
end


local testSlide = newCarousel(myImages)
testSlide.slideToImage()
```

Which gave me this error:

> Attempt to index local "testSlide" (a nil value)...

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to do `testSlide.slideToImage()` you have to modify `newCarousel` so that it returns a table with a function inside it. The simplest implementation is the following:

```
function newCarousel(images)
    local t = {}
    t.slideToImage = function() 
        print("ah!")
    end
    return t
end
```

You can even build t and return it on a single step; the following code is equivalent to the one above:

```
function newCarousel(images)
    return {
        slideToImage = function() 
            print("ah!")
        end
    }
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `newCarousel` returns nothing, so `testSlide` is nil, so when you try to index it (`testSlide.slideToImage` is exactly equivalent to `testSlide["slideToImage"]`) you get an error.

I would recommend reading [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/). You may be able to work out the language's syntax, semantics, and idioms by trial and error, but it'll take you a lot longer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'd accept your answer, but @egarcia solved my problem.

Comment: I second Mud's recommendation to read [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/).  While it's easy to pick up the basics of the language and get some things to work, Lua has some very powerful features that just aren't obvious unless you've read the documentation.

Comment: @Elliot: I was tempted to do that. Note that when egarcia says "simplest solution" he means the simplest thing that will get your broken code to work, but in the larger context of your code (`newCarousel` is creating an object and `slideToImage` is a method) this is *not* the proper solution to your problem. What you really want is a metatable containing your Carousel methods, and a `new` method that applies it to a new object. However, giving you the necessary background to understand that solution would require replicating most of Programming in Lua here, so I just recommended you read it.

Comment: I understand, and appreciate it. I'll be sure to check it out and I'll probably be referencing it quite a lot, but at the moment, I was just trying to solve that one particular problem. I upvoted your question, but accepted egarcia's answer because that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've got now, as [Mud stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054018/attempt-to-index-local-why-am-i-getting-this-error/6054267#6054267), doesn't return anything.  (This is not Scheme or Ruby or the like where the last expression is the return value.)  Further, you seem to be thinking that `newCarousel` is an object.  It isn't.  It's a function.  When you've finished calling `newCarousel` it's over.  It's done its work, whatever that may be (which in your case is creating a local variable that is promptly dropped and returning `nil`).

Correct code for this would look more like:

```
function newCarousel(images) 
    return function() 
        print("ah!")
    end
end

local testSlide = newCarousel(myImages)
testSlide()
```

Here I now have `newCarousel` creating an (anonymous) function and immediately returning it.  This anonymous function is bound to `testSlide` so I can invoke it any time I like for as long as `testSlide` remains in scope.

---

It's instructive to look at the generated code when playing with Lua.  First let's look at what `luac` churns out for your code:

```
main <junk.lua:0,0> (8 instructions, 32 bytes at 0xeb6540)
0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 1 local, 3 constants, 1 function
    1   [5] CLOSURE     0 0 ; 0xeb6720
    2   [1] SETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; newCarousel
    3   [7] GETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; newCarousel
    4   [7] GETGLOBAL   1 -2    ; myImages
    5   [7] CALL        0 2 2
    6   [8] GETTABLE    1 0 -3  ; "slideToImage"
    7   [8] CALL        1 1 1
    8   [8] RETURN      0 1

function <junk.lua:1,5> (2 instructions, 8 bytes at 0xeb6720)
1 param, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 2 locals, 0 constants, 1 function
    1   [4] CLOSURE     1 0 ; 0xeb6980
    2   [5] RETURN      0 1

function <junk.lua:2,4> (4 instructions, 16 bytes at 0xeb6980)
0 params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 2 constants, 0 functions
    1   [3] GETGLOBAL   0 -1    ; print
    2   [3] LOADK       1 -2    ; "ah!"
    3   [3] CALL        0 2 1
    4   [4] RETURN      0 1
```

In your code the mainline creates a closure, binds it to the name `newCarousel`, gets that value, gets the value of `myImages` and does a call.  This corresponds to `local testSlide = newCarousel(myImages)`.  Next it gets the `slideToImage` value from the local table (`testSlide`).  The problem here is that `testSlide` isn't a table, it's `nil`.  This is where your error message is coming from.  This isn't the only error, mind you, but it's the first one the runtime sees and is what's making everything choke.  If you'd returned an actual function from `newCarousel` you'd get a different error.  If, for example, I'd added the line `return slideToImage` to the `newCarousel` function, the error message would have been "attempt to index local 'testSlide' (a function value)".